# How to get 5 items on the basis of minimum quantity from a txt file

Tags: java, file-handling

I want to access the 5 items of a Group that have minimum quantities from a text file

I am able to access the first 5 items from the Group but not the minimum ones from that particular group

```
        List<String> itemsWithMinQuantity = new ArrayList<String>();
        String lineRead;
        int requiredItemsInGroup = 5;
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader("file path");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineRead.contains(("Group ID : " + groupID))) {

                if (requiredItemsInGroup != 0) {
                    itemsWithMinQuantity.add(lineRead);
                } else {
                    break;

                }
                requiredItemsInGroup--;
            }
        }

        if (itemsWithMinQuantity.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.singletonList("No items in entered group No.");

        } else {
            return itemsWithMinQuantity;
        }
    }
```

Expected : 
it should return us the 5 items along with their Group ID and Quantity on the basis of Minimum Quantity from Group

> Actual

```
"Group ID : 1 Quantity : 5 Item Title : MUCHAE NAMUL (DAIKON)",

"Group ID : 1 Quantity : 0 Item Title : LUSH LEMON DRIZZLE!",

"Group ID : 1 Quantity : 0 Item Title : CHOCOLATE GRAVY",

"Group ID : 1 Quantity : 0 Item Title : MICHAEL SYMON'S CHICKEN CUTLET MILANESE WITH ARUGULA SALAD",

"Group ID : 1 Quantity : 0 Item Title : CLASSIC BEEF BRAISE"
```

Comment: You have to read *all* the items belonging to that group id and sort it by quantity to extract the top 5 items

Comment: Sir i am supposed to do this ? @user7

Comment: _First_ you read everything from the file into a list, _then_ you find your 5 items in that list. That’s much easier than doing it all in one step

Answer (score 0):

First, I have created a simple POJO to hold the quantity and the item data (the whole line).

```
private static class Item {
    private int quantity;
    private String itemData;

    private Item(String itemData, int quantity) {
        this.itemData = itemData;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getItemData() {
        return itemData;
    }
}
```

Read each item (belonging to the desired group) and extract the quantity. Create an Item object for each line with this data.

Next, sort the items by their quantity count (`Comparator.comparing(Item::getQuantity)`).

With this, you would have all the items sorted by quantity. All that is left is to print the top 5 items of this list.

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
String lineRead;
FileReader fileReader = null;
try {
    fileReader = new FileReader("...");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Quantity : (\\d+)");
while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (lineRead.contains(("Group ID : " + groupId))) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineRead);
        int quantity;
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected data format. Quantity not found");
        }
        Item item = new Item(lineRead, quantity);
        items.add(item);
    }
}
items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getQuantity));

items.stream()
        .limit(5)
        .forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getItemData()));
```

The regex `Quantity : (\\d+)` matches strings having the word `Quantity` followed by a number. By getting the 1st matching group we get the value of the quantity alone.

The Comparing method reference is just an elegant representation of a traditional comparator.

```
items.sort(new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.getQuantity(), o2.getQuantity());
    }
});
```